# MsiEnumProductsEx returning ERROR_MORE_DATA without doing anything

Tags: windows-installer

On a relatively new XP (SP3) installation, I am getting strange results from calls to `MsiEnumProductsEx` (from msi.lib). Here is my code:

```
    TCHAR userId[8] = _T("s-1-1-0");
    UINT result;
    index = 0;
    TCHAR szInstalledProductCode[39];
    TCHAR szSid[40];
    MSIINSTALLCONTEXT context;
    DWORD numChars = 40;
    MSIINSTALLCONTEXT context;
    result = MsiEnumProductsEx(NULL, userId, MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_ALL, index, szInstalledProductCode, &context, (LPTSTR)szSid, &numChars);
```

After this function call, all output variables remain unchanged; that is, `szInstalledProductCode`, `szSid`, `context` and `numChars` remain the same; tested by actually giving them dummy values and seeing that they weren't overwritten. Furthermore, `result` is set to 234; which is usually the indication that the `szSid` buffer is too small, and that I need to pass in a larger buffer; the `numChars` variable should be filled with this size. However, as previously mentioned, numChars is left exactly as it was before (40), so calling the method again with the same size (plus one for null termination) does nothing different to the first time.

When I run this same code on other machines, it behaves exactly how the documentation says it should behave - filling all the variables, including `szSid` up to its buffer length; and if the buffer is too small, returning `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and filling `numChars` with the appropriate size.

So all I can think of is that this install of Windows is somehow broken, but we need to understand the root cause of what specifically is wrong in Windows. Can anyone give me guidance; even if it's just certain avenues to investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this one:

I used ProcessMonitor from SysInternals to see what it was doing behind the scenes (comparing this to using ProcessMonitor on a machine that was actually working). I noticed that the difference was that as soon as it looked in HKCR/Installer/Products, it started tying up the process (whereas on the working PC, it then proceeded to get installer info from the registry). It turned out that there was a malformed Product Code (somehow a hyphen at the start of it) in there, and so the function was failing. No idea how it got there, but there you go.

Comment: Similar yet different strange things: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/11/curious-case-of-corrupted-characters.html